# Adding borders and background color with iTextSharp to PdfFormField

Tags: c#, colors, background, itext

I want to add borders and background color to my PdfFormField. Now background color is activated only after I write something to text field but before that it is just white. And I can't get borders to show up.

This is my code:

```
public void addField(PdfWriter writer, string name, int x, int y, int w, int h, PdfContentByte cb, int maxSize, string text, BaseFont font, int border)
        {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x, y-h, x+w, y);
        // Change the font Widths
        //BaseFont font = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        float fontSize = 12;

        //int[] widths = font.Widths;
        //for (int k = 0; k < widths.Length; k++)
        //{
        //if (widths[k] != 0)
        //widths[k] = width;
        //}
        font.ForceWidthsOutput = true;
        string all = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-*/+.,\"'():;,?./!$+=_{[]}&éèàêîâ";

        //Color textColor = BaseColor.RED;
        // Create the Acroform TextField

        PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateTextField(writer, PdfFormField.SINGLELINE, PdfFormField.PLAINTEXT, maxSize);
        field.FieldName = name;
        field.DefaultValueAsString = text;

        //ield.GetTextField();
        field.MKBackgroundColor = BaseColor.RED;

        //field.BackgroundColor = new GrayColor(0.75f);
        //field.BorderColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
        //field.BorderWidth = 1;
        //field.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED;

        field.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
        field.SetPage();
        writer.AddAnnotation(field);

        // Position the field on the page
        field.SetWidget(rec, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);

        // Create apperance so the field Size and font match what we want
        PdfAppearance tp = cb.CreateAppearance(rec.Right-rec.Left, rec.Top-rec.Bottom);
        PdfAppearance da = (PdfAppearance)tp.Duplicate;
        da.SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize);
        da.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
        field.DefaultAppearanceString = da;

        // Fill the default value of the field

        tp.BeginVariableText();
        tp.SaveState();
        tp.Rectangle(rec);
        tp.Clip();
        tp.NewPath();
        tp.BeginText();
        tp.SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize);
        tp.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
        tp.SetTextMatrix(100,100);
        tp.ShowText(all);
        tp.SetTextMatrix(2,(rec.Top-rec.Bottom)/2-(fontSize*0.3f));
        tp.ShowText(text);
        tp.EndText();
        tp.RestoreState();
        tp.EndVariableText();

        field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp);
}
```

Comment: Please, post only relevant code. Remove insignificant sections of commented out code

Comment: Consider adding a rectangle with the desired colour to the page content.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code i hope it works

```
PdfFormField field = .......;
field.setMKBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
field.setMKBackgroundColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
```

Comment: This code is not formatted. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to write posts on SO. Also your code lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.